# Changing FSMO Roles: Access Denied

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to change FSMO roles of an active directory server by connecting it from a remote server using Invoke-Command. The script is below:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -Credential $icred -ScriptBlock {

$global:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
import-module activedirectory;

Move-ADDirectoryServerOperationMasterRole -Identity owinfadc01 -OperationMasterRole 0,1,2 -Force -Confirm:$false ;

}
```

The problem is that

> Move-ADDirectoryServerOperationMasterRole

changes the role of PDC; however, gets "Access is denied" error while trying for RID pool manager. The weird thing is "RID pool manager" and "Infrastructure Library" roles are changed either after waiting couple of minutes.

As a note, my user is a member of both Administrator and Domain Admins.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried moving each role 1 by 1 instead of all at once? `0..2 |%{Move-ADDirectoryServerOperationMasterRole -OperationMasterRole $_}`

Comment: No, I have not. Does it create a big difference ? @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: I don't know, but I would attempt it :)

Comment: No difference :) @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case one faces with this problem, I add the solution.

Add "-credential" property to the command. After modification, it looks like below:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -Credential $icred -ScriptBlock {

$global:ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
import-module activedirectory;

Move-ADDirectoryServerOperationMasterRole -Identity owinfadc01 -Credential $icred -OperationMasterRole 0,1,2 -Force -Confirm:$false ;

}
```

Note that $cred is the variable that contains required username/password combination and the process is the same as Shift+RightClick powershell and select "Run as different user". In addition, if you are using Invoke-Command as I do, do not forget to add "-ArgumentList" property to Invoke-Command in order to transfer the credential defined before(outside Invoke-Command).

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem (or one that behaves very like it).

I am not using **Invoke-Command** but **Enter-PSSession** instead.

**Move-ADDirectoryServerOperationMasterRole** would succeed for every role but SchemaMaster.

I have been running my Active Directory environment since 2014 and it never occurred to me to add my EA account to the "Schema Admins" group!

Added my account to "Schema Admins", log out, log in, problem solved.

Comment: I had the same issue and your suggestion of adding the "Schema Admins" group to the user I was trying to run the powersheel command on then logging off worked great. 
 Just logged back on as usual and ran `Move-ADDirectoryServerOperationMasterRole -Identity "dc1" SchemaMaster` to move the schema role over as well.  None of the other roles required me to do something like that.

Answer (score -2):

Just run the PowerShell as Administrator (via Right-Click).